# Including a second query in Entity Framework LINQ Query

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I've got a table "Houses" and "Cats", which contains the columns "Id" and "HouseName" and "Id" and "CatName".

Now I got a table "HouseCatAssignments", where I store the relations between the Cats and the Houses (the Cat can live in more than one house and one house can store more than one cat).

This table looks like:
Id, CatId, HouseId

"CatId" is bound to Cats.Id and HouseId is bound to Houses.Id.

Now I want to display the Table "House" in a datagrid that also contains a field for "CatCount" - a counter for the value of how many cats are living in this house.

How should I now query my tables so I have all the values of "Houses" and an additional Column that contains the *Cat-Count* for the specific house?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Entity Framework it should have automatically added navigation properties that allow you to do the following query:

```
var housesWithCount = context.Houses
                             .Select( h=> new 
                              { 
                                 Id = h.Id, 
                                 HouseName = h.HouseName,
                                 CatCount = h.Cats.Count() 
                              });
```